# how to check session has been expired in java?

Tags: java, session, servlets

Is there any other way to check expiry of session other than this

session.isNew()

Answer (score 31):

Yes:

- you can call `HttpServletRequest.getSession(false)` and you'll get a `null` instead of a session if there isn't one active already.
- you can define a lifecycle listener (using `HttpSessionListener`) in your `web.xml`. That way you can get notified the moment a session bites the dust.

Comment: +1 for the second suggestion. BTW, its good to name it, so HttpSessionListener is the one.

Comment: Implementing `HttpSessionListener` is the way to go. Just hook on `sessionDestroyed()`.

Answer (score 25):

With `session.isNew` you can not distinguish expired sessions from entirely new sessions.
You can check if the session has expired and/or timed out with:

```
if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null
        && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
    // Session is expired
}
```

Use `getRequestedSessionId` to distinguish between new and existing (valid/expired) sessions, and use `isRequestedSessionIdValid` to distinguish betwheen valid and new/expired sessions.

You can put this code in a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html).