# Spring Security - display HTML page on expiredUrl in sessionManagement

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to configure `expiredUrl(" ")` feature in my java spring security.
I want to display HTML page when my concurrent session get expired
I tried in following way:-

**JAVA**

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionFixation()
            .changeSessionId()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .expiredUrl("/session_expired.html")
}
```

My context path set as `localhost:8080/context_path`
but
I am not getting how to display `session_expired.html` page on expiredUrl call
I am using angularJs on Js side
Please help me to display Html page on expiredUrl call

AND

If I tried with the help of Js then my code is:-

**JAVA**

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionFixation()
            .changeSessionId()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .expiredUrl("/access/session_expired")
}
```

**ANGULARJS**

```
$stateProvider.state('session_expired', {
     'url': '/session_expired',
     'templateUrl': '/session_expired.html',
     'controller': 'SessionExpiredController'
})

.factory('SessionService', function ($resource, restRoot, contextPath) {
return $resource({
    'session_expired': {
        'url': contextPath + '/access/session_expired'
    },
})

.controller('SessionExpiredController', function (SessionService, $state) {
     SessionService.session_expired(function () {
         $state.go("session_expired");
     });
 });
```

here when session get expired it will goes on link  `localhost:8080/context_path/session_expired#/landing...`
but I want to go on link
`localhost:8080/context_path/#/session_expired`

**OR**

I want to display direct HTML page on `expiredUrl`
so please guide me how to do this.

Comment: Did you try something from StackOverflow like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070179/how-to-check-session-has-been-expired-in-java ? And just forward to your page? Or create Filter and check it (and redirect) there? Maybe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026846/how-to-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-is-expired-in-java-web-application

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is working for me:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/list")
                .access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
                .antMatchers("/newuser/**", "/delete-user-*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')").antMatchers("/edit-user-*")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password").and()
                .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }
```

Comment: yes but I want to display HTML page on session expired, so when my session get expired that time it goes on path `localhost:8080/context_path/session_expired#/...`
instead of this I want to redirect to `localhost:8080/context_path/#/session_expired` **OR** I want to return html page in `expiredUrl`

Comment: ok and what is that `/Access_Denied` ? is it any link or something else ?

Comment: its a AccessDenied page that will be shown if the users is not allowed to go to certain url’s..

Comment: can you please share me that code, how you are showing AccessDenied page

Comment: the code is shared.. for example if an user with role 'USER' try to type the delete URL in browser-bar and enter.He should see AccessDenied page.. only user with 'Admin' role can access to delete URL in my example..