# Spring security and session timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security to authenticate user in my web platform developed with Spring.
I would like to manage session timeout errors through redirect on login page  but I can't find anything about default timeout, so I found

```
http.sessionManagement()
    .maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login.html")
    .invalidSessionUrl("/login.html");
```

but I read also about

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("==== Session is created ====");
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("==== Session is destroyed ====");
    }
}
```

so, since it is a delicate task I'd need an advice: with  `event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60);` i can set timeout and with `expiredUrl("/login.html")` I can catch errors about expired session and redirect to login page?Is it correct? Thanks

***UPDATE***: I tryed with this code (my old code plus invalidSessionUrl and expiredUrl) but it always goes on the invalidSession.html page and then I have to return to main page. Further logout goes on login page and not on login?logout page

```
http
    .authorizeRequests() //Authorize Request Configuration
    .anyRequest().hasAnyRole(rolesArray)//.authenticated()
    .and() //Login Form configuration for all others
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html").maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/sessionExpired.html");
```

Comment: try this configuration :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108663/spring-ssecurity-display-html-page-on-expiredurl-in-sessionmanagement/38109554?noredirect=1#comment63671861_38109554

Comment: my configuration is much different from yours